# Cauchy's theorem with and without Green's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I know two main approaches to proof of Cauchy's theorem ($\oint_{\gamma}^{}f(z)dz=0$ for any simple connected contour $\gamma$ and any function $f$ holomorphic inside $\gamma$). First is based on Green's theorem and takes just a few lines: $$ \oint_{\gamma}^{}f(z)dz=\oint_{\gamma}(u(x,y)+iv(x,y))(dx+idy)=\oint_{\gamma}(u\enspace dx - v\enspace dy) + i\oint_{\gamma}(u\enspace dy + v\enspace dx)=\int \int_{\Gamma}(-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y})dxdy + i \int \int_{\Gamma}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial y})dxdy = 0$$
where the last equality follows from Cauchy-Riemann equations. 
Second (Goursat theorem) proves special case when the contour is a triangle and then extrapolate result on polygons and convex contours. It's quite a classic, but for the sake of completeness I'll attach proof (from '*Complex Analysis*' by John M. Howie). 
[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj5tT.png) 
**Question 1:** I read everywhere (including Wikipedia) that the proof based on Green's theorem is 'worse' in a sense that it assumes continuity of partial derivatives $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x},\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial v }{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$, which is unnecessary. However, to my understanding the proof of Goursat theorem uses this assumption too, because it says that function has to be holomorphic everywhere inside contour. The same author defines holomorphic function as differentiable at every point in some open set $U \subseteq  \mathbb{C}$ . He also states that the sufficient condition for a function to be differentiable at point $c$ is the continuity of its partial derivatives in some vicinity of $c$, beside Cauchy-Riemann equations. (*He provides an example $f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ with $u(x,y) = \sqrt{|xy|}$ and $v(x,y) = 0$ and shows that derivative is not defined at $(0,0)$ despite C-R eq. are trivially satisfied*). 
So, as I see, the continuity of partials is already assumed implicitly. If the answer is that in a proof only local differentiability is used, then 
**Question 2:** If there is a singularity inside a contour, at which point the proof of Goursat theorem breaks? If we only use the local differentiability in a point inside all the triangles, then singularities outside inner triangles should have no affect, which I know to be wrong.


Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: “As I see, the continuity of partials is assumed implicitly.” No. The case where partial derivatives are continuous is (*a priori*) just that, an *example*, but Goursat’s proof does not need it.  2) because you select each time a triangle with a “large” contour integral, you’re driven towards a singularity (if it exists).

Comment: @Aphelli So the continuity of partial derivatives is not a necessary condition for a complex function to have a derivative? If so, then doesn't function in my answer provides a counterexample (the one with u = sqrt(abs(x*y)) and v = 0 at point (0,0) )? If it is false, then aren't we assuming their continuity in the moment when we're taking derivative?

Comment: You do not want to involve partial derivatives in any way near the definition of holomorphic functions. The correct definition is that the function must be (real-)differentiable at the point, and that the derivative is the multiplication by a complex number. Then Goursat’s theorem is that, given a function $f$ holomorphic at every point of an open subset $U \subset \mathbb{C}$, given a convex polygon $P \subset U$, the contour integral of $f$ on the boundary of $P$ vanishes.

Comment: @Aphelli [Complex Analysis, John M. Howie] '...and suppose that the partial derivatives exist and are continuous throughout D. Suppose also that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied at c. Then f is differentiable at c'
[Complex Analysis for Mathematics and Engineering, John H. Mathews] ‘… If all the partial derivatives are continuous at the point z_0 and if the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold, then f is differentiable at z_0 ‘
More citations would not fit in the comment, but in these and many other books I find the opposite of what you've said

Comment: That’s because “continuous partial derivatives near a given point” is equivalent to “$C^1$ near this point”, which is a condition that involve differentials instead of partial derivatives. Your own example shows very well why partial derivatives are not enough: the partial derivatives are not both defined at every point $(t,0)$ with $t \neq 0$, so you don’t get differentiability. Additionally, “differentiable on an open subset+Cauchy-Riemann” is enough to prove Goursat’s theorem and thus imply analyticity.

Comment: @Aphelli Okay, thank you